# Shell script to fetch a value from a file and save it to other

Tags: bash, shell, sh, cut

I have some text in one file which I want to be copied to another file, using shell script.

This is the script -

```
#!/bin/sh

PROPERTY_FILE=/path/keyValuePairs.properties

function getValue {
   FIELD_KEY=$1
   FIELD_VALUE=`cat $PROPERTY_FILE | grep "$FIELD_KEY" | cut --complement -d'=' -f1`
}

SERVER_FILE=/path/FileToReplace.yaml

getValue "xyz.abc"
sed -i -e "s|PASSWORD|$FIELD_VALUE|g" $SERVER_FILE
```

keyValuePairs.properties:

```
xyz.abc=abs
```

FileToReplace.yaml:

```
someField:
    address: "someValue"
    password: PASSWORD
```

The goal of the script is to fetch "abs" from keyValuePairs.properties and replace it in FileToReplace.yaml from PASSWORD field. 
The FileToReplace.yaml **should look like**

```
someField:
    address: "someValue"
    password: abs
```

Note - Instead of "abs", there could be '=' in the text. It should work fine too.

The **current situation** is that when I run the script, it updates FileToReplace.yaml as

```
someField:
    address: "someValue"
    password:
```

**It is setting the value as empty.**

Can someone please help me figure what's wrong with this script?

Note - Whenever I execute the script, I get the issue -

```
sh scriptToRun.sh 
cut: illegal option -- -
usage: cut -b list [-n] [file ...]
       cut -c list [file ...]
       cut -f list [-s] [-d delim] [file ...]
```

***If I use gcut, the code just works fine, but I can't use gcut (requirement issues). I need to fix this using cut.***

Comment: should `$PROP_KEY` be `$FIELD_KEY`?

Comment: That is correct. Thanks for pointing out!

Comment: But still, the same issue is there. I edited the text on this post though.

Comment: try changing cut to `cut -d'=' -f2` or running in bash rather than sh, unless that's a requirement

Comment: The line `cat $PROPERTY_FILE | grep "$FIELD_KEY"` can be rewritten as `grep "$FIELD_KEY" $PROPERTY_FILE` directly to avoid [_Useless use of cat_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29#Useless_use_of_cat).

Answer (score 0):

Replace the cut command with:

> cut -d'=' -f2-

and it should work on all versions of cut.

-f2- means field 2 and all later. This is necessary to handle values containing '='s.

And yes, some characters will cause problems for the sed command.  It's hard to get a robust solution without getting into trouble here. A python script may be the better choice.

If shell script is the only option, you could try something like this:

```
(sed -n -e '1,/PASSWORD/p' FileToReplace.yaml | head -n -1;
echo "    password: ${FIELD_VALUE}";
sed -n -e '/PASSWORD/,$ p' FileToReplace.yaml) > FileToReplace.yaml.new \
&& mv FileToReplace.yaml.new FileToReplace.yaml
```

but it gets quite ugly. (print the file up to the line containing "PASSWORD", then echo the full password line, then print the rest of the file)

You can also use something like this:

```
cat << EOF > FileToCreate.yaml
someField:
    address: "someValue"
    password: ${FIELD_VALUE}
```

if keeping the old contents of the file is not important.

Comment: This works just fine! But if I just use "&" in keyValuePairs.properties (xyz.abc=&), then it doesn't replace the value in FileToReplace.yaml. Any way to make that work?

Comment: What's exactly the difference between "-f2" and "-f2-" ?

Comment: Just like &, the script is not able to handle these characters /  : "

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your script:

1. `FIELD_VALUE` is local to the `getValue()` function.
2. `getValue()` will match rows containing `FIELD_KEY` anywhere in the line (e.g. `some.property=string.containing.xyz.abc`)
3. `getValue()` could return multiple rows.
4. All occurrences of the string "PASSWORD" in the server file will be updated, not just the ones on the "password: PASSWORD" line.

If you can use `bash` instead of `sh`, this should resolve all of the issues:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare    property_file=/path/keyValuePairs.properties
declare    server_file=/path/FileToReplace.yaml
declare    property="xyz.abc"

property_line=$(grep -m 1 "^${property}=" ${property_file}" )

sed -i 's|^\(\s*password:\s*\)PASSWORD\s$|\1'${property_line##*=}'|g' ${server_file}
```

Comment: My script still has some issues: 1) It does not check that it is updating the password field in the correct section of the file. If there are multiple sections containing password fields they will all be updated. 2) The script will not find the property if the appropriate line in the properties file contains white space. If these issues are important, let me know. They can be fixed with more code.

Answer (score 0):

The original code which I posted, worked. I was using the wrong name of the file in the shell (in my real code) which was causing it to not read the value and hence setting it to empty.